# How to ignore/exclude the migration and seeding of certain tables

Tags: javascript, postgresql, database-migration, knex.js, objection.js

> Currently i have to seed all the files even though there is change in a single file csv. Is there a way that we can seed only a specific file while data seeded in the previous/existing files remains as it is in DB.

Also i wanted to know if we can **separate migration & seed folders** so that they don't conflict with each other. I want to do this because when i change a particular migration file it throws error specially on foreign key part. So i think if we move it to *separate folder* than that should solve the error. Please suggest.

```
npm run migrate
```

Comment: please add more details to the problem

Comment: Normally we rollback all the tables in DB, perform migration of all tables & seed all the tables with the new data via csv files. But now we have come across a condition where we want to keep the data of table called "selection" to remain as it is whereas data of remaining tables in DB should be reset & loaded with new data. In short, is there a way where we can exclude a particular file during seed. Other way we found is to one by one seed all the files which we want & exclude "selection.csv" but this is cumbersome & time consuming.

Comment: can you include the code that gets the csv files